# A few issues with objective C coding

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective C and I have a couple of quick questions:

I have an NSMutableArray *myArray and I want to release it so I wrote [myArray release]; But I get an error saying "ARC forbids explicit message send of release". Why is this and how do I fix it?

Secondly, I'm having a trouble with app delegates. The tutorial I'm following tells us to use the following two lines of code as part of the process to make a popup menu:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appDelegate.viewController.detailItem =
[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

However, I get an error at "appDelegate.viewController" because it says viewController is not a valid property.

For reference, here is the tutorial I am using:

http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: I figured since they were two quick questions it would be fine to put them together instead of cluttering the site with more questions.

Comment: ARC is Automated Reference Counting and doesn't allow manual reference counting with release. So either remove the release or switch off ARC.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your tutorial appears to predate ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). When using ARC, you don't need to worry about manual `retain`/`release` calls, since the compiler takes care of that for you.
2. Your tutorial refers to `PopOverExample1AppDelegate.h` but I can't see where that file is. You may have to modify the instructions to suit your own application.

Comment: I'm using the default AppDelegate.h that comes when you start a new Single View Application project in XCode.

Comment: Ok, does that `AppDelegate.h` file declare a `viewController` property? (I'm not at my Mac right now so I can't check.)

Comment: No, but the way the tutorial explains things it made it seem like it was a default property of AppDelegates so I figured I'd give it a try.